# OpenSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 104

Tags: php, curl

I am posing order-data on ssl means (https) based api via curl, But it return **OpenSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 104** message.

Here is my test code as per client required json:

```
$apiKey = "xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx";
$privatekey = "xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx";
$timestamp = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // (for example: 2016-07-19 14:05:55)

$signature = hash_hmac('sha1', $timestamp, $apiKey);
$signature = hash_hmac('sha1', $privatekey, $signature);

$postURL = "https://www.compu-cover.com/intelligent-rewards/orders/?OrderNo=123";

$orderInfo['Order'] = array(
        "apiKey" => $apiKey,
        "privatekey" => $privatekey,
        "Signature" => $signature,
        "Timestamp" => $timestamp,
        "Firstname" => "Ajay",
        "Surname" => "Sharma",
        "EmailAddress" => "ajay@yopmail.com",
        "DaytimeTel" => "0141798526",
        "EveningTel" => "0141798526",
        "MobileTel" => "9887654321",
        "Address1" => "A-5",
        "Address2" => "Jhalana",
        "Address3" => "Jaipur",
        "Address4" => "Rajasthan",
        "County" => "India",
        "Postcode" => "302019", 
        "Cover" => "ADTBL",
        "Scheme" => 2, 
        "Premium" => 5,
        "EquipmentQty" => 1,
        "EquipmentType1" => "Smartphone",
        "EquipmentMake1" => "Moto",
        "EquipmentModel1" => "Moto G",
        "EquipmentPrice1" => 100
    );

$params = json_encode($orderInfo);

$session = curl_init($postURL);

curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true); 

$response = curl_exec($session);

if (FALSE === $response) {
    var_dump(curl_error($session));
    var_dump(curl_errno($session));
}

curl_close($session);
$response = json_decode($response);

var_dump($response);
```

How to find reason for the failure? What could be the reason for failure? kindly provide your suggestions.

Comment: Are you running this in docker?

Comment: Not sure if this is related to your problem, but is seems like you're missing a CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER.

Answer (score 14):

In the standard C library the variable `errno` contains the code for what went wrong with the most recent system call. The value of 104 is defined as `ECONNRESET` which means "Connection reset by peer".

The error simply means the other side hung up on you, without completing the normal HTTPS protocol and giving back anything in return ... possibly for all sorts of reasons, could be network problems, or server-side program crash, or the other end simply does not like what you did. It's not really related to OpenSSL at all, and to know what caused it you would need access to the server logs.

Answer (score 3):

There are probably many reasons you might get this.

For me, I got this because I was using curl and the web site I was accessing didn't like curl being used.  I fixed this with:

```
curl -A "Mozilla Chrome Safari" someserver.com/somepage.html
```

This tells curl to say to the server, 'hey I'm a browser'.   You can use your favourite browser to get a nicer newer string, go to the browser developer console typically under 'network' you can see individual request items and there you can get the string your current browser sends as the 'user-agent'.

The reason why a website would do this is your typical customer doesn't use curl.  Best case a curl will be a bot using up server resource, worst case it's an evil hacker.

Answer (score 2):

I've received this error, and gotten around it simply by waiting a half hour and trying again.

Comment: Yeah, before I was able to `curl` w/o any problem all the time, but got this error today whereas no code change at all. Feels like a network issue and could occur from time to time, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue.

```
OpenSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 104
```

I guessed the error was regarded openssl or etc.
But, it was not.

In my case, one of POST parameters was wrong value. (something like OTP code)
And I resolved it finally.

Answer (score 0):

I also realized was missing post data information. After doing so everything worked as expected

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting the error while posting the data to a domain

OpenSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 104

I got a solution, as mentioned by LazyBrush, you can set the user agents in curl as per following:

```
$data_string_ary = array(SOME ARRAY INDEXES);
$data_string = json_encode($data_string_ary);
$url = 'someserver.com/somepage.html';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla Chrome Safari');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Authorization: YOUR AUTHORIZATION CODE'
));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $result;
```

It works like a charm for me. Hope this will help for you too.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly this will happen if you dont have proper Internet connection. Try is once again, it worked for me

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

try

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).