# cURL error 56: OpenSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 104

Tags: php, ajax, guzzle

Hi I am sending file to server side that require integration service uses TLS/SSL.
Below is my code sending file

```
    $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client(['base_uri' => 'https://secure.urganda.com/api/submissions/test@analysis.urganda.com/']);

    $response = $client->request('POST', 'dsd', [

        'headers' => [
              'User-Agent' =>  $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],
              'Host' => 'secure.urganda.com',
              'Accept' => 'application/json',
              'Content-Type'  => $type,
              'x-urkund-submitter'  => 'test2@analysis.urganda.com',
              'x-urkund-filename'  => $filename,
              'Content-Length'  => $size,
              'Authorization' => 'Basic '. base64_encode($username.':'.$password)
            ],
            
            
        'contents' => fopen($path, 'r')
        
        
    ]);

    echo $response->getStatusCode();
    echo $response->getBody();
```

Then i get error **cURL error 56: OpenSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 104** anyone know what is the problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OpenSSL SSL\_read: SSL\_ERROR\_SYSCALL, errno 104](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46195374/openssl-ssl-read-ssl-error-syscall-errno-104)